# How to Restrict Access to a Page with PHP if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a PHP project with user account status in the database. It contains status such as active, inactive, suspended etc. I need an if statement in the index page that can Restrict access to a particular page or link if the account is set to inactive.

Your response is great appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: `if ($status === 'inactive') die();` anything else?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to prevent links to certain pages from showing to users that didn't have a status of active, you might do something like this:

```
<!-- Non active state links -->
<a href="/about">About us</a>
<a href="/contact">Contact us</a>

<!-- Active state only link -->
<?php
  if($user->status === 'active'){
    echo '<a href="/admin">My Account</a>';
  }
?>
```

Then on each of the restricted pages themselves, you might do something like this:

```
<?php
   if($user->status !== 'active'){
      echo "Forbidden!";
      die();
   }

   *** The rest of your code here ***
?>
```

To prevent access to a particular page, you need the logic to be present on that page, you can't control who can access what solely from the index page.

Comment: Thank you so Much. This solved what has taken my whole day. God bless you.

Comment: I used this particular code on the page i intend to restrict if user is Inactive <?php
   if($user->status !== 'active'){
      echo "Forbidden!";
      die();
   }

   *** The rest of your code here ***
?>  but i noticed that it is simply restricting the page irrespective of status. If i change the status back to active, it keeps restricting

Comment: You're most welcome. To be clear the $user->status part is an illustration of what you might be using to get the parameter. It should be replaced with whatever existing code you have to determine the status of the user.

Answer (score -2):

I suppose you are using Native PHP:

At the file which contains the code you want to restrict:

```
<?php
if(!$myUser->isActive){ //User is not active
    header(File you want to redirect in case is not active.php)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the code but even if i change the status back to active it keeps redirecting to my preferred header location. It's just working without regard to the condition